# Eclipse Web Application Project. Introduced CSS properties doesn't work

Tags: css, eclipse, web-applications, properties

I created a new Web Application Project. But if I edit my `war/Sandbox_Project.css`, the `localhost:8080/Sandbox_Project` web page isn't affected. E.g., if I add a new property `body` and some values, there is no effect. But if I change automatically added example properties, everything works.

**Automatically added when creating the project. It works.**

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777777;
    margin: 40px 0px 70px;
    text-align: center;
    background: fuchsia; // I added it
}

.sendButton {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-style: italic; // I added it
}
```

**I added this property and it doesn't work.**

```
body {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are having a cache issue. Try pressing "CTRL + F5" in your browser once you make a change in your CSS file.

Comment: Agree to @maqjav. +1. You need to clear your cache, cookies and still it does not work, restart the browser as well as rebuild the solution in eclipse.

Comment: @maqjav, @NathanLee, it didn't work for me. If you have a little time, please download my project from [GitHub](https://github.com/Red-Planet/Sandbox_Wap), edit the CSS file and run. I use `JBoss 7.1` as a server. But I also tested on App Engine and the CSS chages were ignored.

Comment: @RedPlanet I've been checking your project, I cannot deploy it because I can't download GWT here, but I see that your content is in the war directory. If you want to deploy it locally all your content must be in the WebContent folder. Try moving it there and reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things you can try.

1. Clear your cache & try again.
2. Rename your CSS File
3. !important may be worth a try.
4. Edit your CSS file then make sure that the changes are in the file linked to your page
5. Create a new css file, link it up then try again.
6. Use chrome dev tools to see whats going on.

Try this

```
body{
   background: #FF0 !important; // Just to see if it works.
}
```

## Dev Tools Steps

> - Open Chrome dev tools (i use F12)
> - Right click on the body and click inspect element.
> - Look at the css panel to see whats going on.
> - if the background color is crossed out then something else is over-riding it
> - else it's more than likely a cache issue.
> - Rename your css file. or you can  add something like this to your css something.css?this=renameIngYourCSSFile

By trying all of this you should get some idea of what's going on.

Comment: I have already fixed the problem. `body {
    background: green;
}` doesn't work for me but `#body_id {
 background: #E6E6E6;
}` and `<body id="body_id">` do! Thanks anyway for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with GWT and JBoss, I suggest you to use the plugin JBoss GWT Integration in the package JBoss Tools, that will help you to create a normal Web application project but using GWT.

Here you have information about how to make it: [Create a project with GWT + JBoss](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreateGWTProjectsWithJBossToolsAndEclipseWTP)

If you don't use this plugin, you will have to move the content from the war folder to the WebContent folder in order to make it work in localhost, or copy your war directory into the webapp folder of your server.

Comment: `JBoss Tools` are just some tools from JBoss, I mean, you can use those tools with whatever version of JBoss server (I used it with JBoss 4 and 5). Here you have an example of a website where they explain how to start JBoss 7 in Eclipse with JBoss Tools: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Starting+JBoss+AS+from+Eclipse+with+JBoss+Tools

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. I took part in another project. The [Create a project with GWT + JBoss](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreateGWTProjectsWithJBossToolsAndEclipseWTP) could be the solution I needed if I used `JBoss Tools 3.2.x` or `JBoss Tools 3.3.x`. But I use `JBoss AS 7.1`